# Selenium Python XPATH how to select input field which is in post form?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two form in same page like below

```
<form method="get">
     <input type="submit">
</form>

<form method="post">
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I am able to get last input field like

```
//input[last()]
```

I need to track the input field if it's a post method form input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following xpath:

```
.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@method="post"]//input')
```

Or the css selector looks better:

```
.find_element_by_css_selector('form[method="post"] > input')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of forms using the XPath. Then extract its method attribute as below:

```
//form/[@method='post']
```

Once you have the form you can get the descendant as below:

```
//form/descendant::input[@type='submit']
```

This should return you the value.